# User input in dialog box

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Is there any library available in python for the graphical user entry input. I know about `tk` but I believe it takes some line of codes to do that. I am looking for the shortest solution.

```
a = input('Enter your string here:')
```

In place of this, I want to get a dialogue box so that user can input there.

This did not serve the purpose. This only shows the dialogue box and you can't provide an input entry.

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.   
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Your text", "Your title", 1)
```

Comment: Its Ok . :) I want to avoid external libraries .

Comment: @iCodez and RishuA. It is rather confusing for others when you delete the first part of a conversation but not the rest.

Comment: Ah ! Seems while editing got deleted . Was from cell phone.

Comment: This is what I am using.
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
in_csv_file = simpledialog.askstring("Some_Name", "Enter CSV file Name",parent=root)

Comment: RishuA: To format code in comments, use the backtick(` ) character, enclosing the code in them. Like this: `root = tk.Tk()` `root.withdraw()` `in_csv_file = simpledialog.askstring("Some_Name", "Enter CSV file Name",parent=root)`

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this .Will edit .

Comment: Somehow I am not able to to get the edit option.

Comment: RishuA: You have 2mins to edit a comment. Delete, repost, then delete this thread of comments.

Comment: Got it. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 13):

You have two choices for a solution. There are two packages you can pip to get, one is easygui, the other is easygui_qt. easygui is based on tcl, and easygui_qt is based on the qt Window manager and is a little more difficult to set up, but just as simple to use, with a few more options.

All they require to use is to import the package, `import easygui`, and after that, to get a user response you would use one line...

```
myvar = easygui.enterbox("What, is your favorite color?")
```

Google "python easygui" for more detailed info.
You can get easygui from [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=easygui).

Comment: The problem is that I want to avoid the external libraries , only want to use available with python install due to some valid reason in my environment.

Comment: Saying `easygui` is based on tcl is a slightly misleading. Internally it uses `tkinter` which is a standard Python library for interfacing to tk/tcl. @RishuAl: Even if you can't use a third-party library, it would probably be very useful for you to do download `easygui` and look at its source code (i.e. how the `enterbox()` function is implemented).

Comment: @martineau Thank You sir . Will definitely have a look to that.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is the shortest you'll get without anything external:

---

To start:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
```

---

Instead of `a=input('enter something')`:

```
a=StringVar()
Label(root, text='enter something').pack()
Entry(root, textvariable=a).pack()
Button(root, text='Ok', command=lambda:DoSomethingWithInput(a.get)).pack()
```

With a function `DoSomethingWithInput(a)`

---

Instead of `print('some text')`:

```
Label(root, text='some text').pack()
Button(root, text='Ok', command=DoSomething).pack()
```

With `DoSomething()` as what you do next.

Comment: Thank you ! Tk am aware. :) You are really putting efforts and I respect that .

Comment: RishuA: You can easily create custom dialog boxes with `tkinter`. Here's some (dated Python 2) [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm), but it you search online (including this website) you'll probably be able to locate more current information.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a module I created a while ago to manage basic printing and input with GUI. It uses tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *


def donothing(var=''):
    pass


class Interface(Tk):
    def __init__(self, name='Interface', size=None):
        super(interface, self).__init__()
        if size:
            self.geometry(size)
        self.title(name)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()

    def gui_print(self, text='This is some text', command=donothing):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        Label(self.frame, text=text).pack()
        Button(self.frame, text='Ok', command=command).pack()

    def gui_input(self, text='Enter something', command=donothing):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()        
        Label(self.frame, text=text).pack()
        entry = StringVar(self)
        Entry(self.frame, textvariable=entry).pack()
        Button(self.frame, text='Ok', command=lambda: command(entry.get())).pack()

    def end(self):
        self.destroy()

    def start(self):
        mainloop()


# -- Testing Stuff --

def foo(value):
    global main
    main.gui_print(f'Your name is {value}.', main.end)


def bar():
    global main
    main.gui_input('What is your name?', foo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = interface('Window')
    bar()
    main.start()
```

It includes an example of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But Instead i can use root= tk.Tk()
rootwithdraw()
in = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "blba bla" Name",parent=root)

Comment: As mentioned I do not want to use any external libraries due to some reasons.

Comment: @RishuA Just copy it into your code, and leave off everything after `if __name__=='__main__':`

Comment: I understood your point . My intention for this question was for the shortest solution(shortest code) . Check my Question. However, i really appreciate your effort to write it for me. i'll definetly try it when needed.

Comment: @RishuA I think the standard tk three lines of code is the best you'll get without anything external. (three lines for input or one for print)

Comment: Yeah, as of now it seems so.

Answer (score 2):

Use turtle. `turtle.textinput("title", "prompt")`

Here is an example:

```py
from turtle import textinput

name = textinput("Name", "Please enter your name:")

print("Hello", name + "!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import simpledialog
item = simpledialog.askstring("New Item", "Enter name of item:")
print(item)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html
Not many lines needed for tkinter :)

Comment: Trying this, I get a Runtime Error: "Too early to create dialog window: no default root window"

Comment: Excellent answer. It is simple and gets the job done without fuss.