# Python 3 Constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So my assignment is asking for rectangle class with default values of 1 and 1 for width and height. It wants a non argument constructor and another constructor to create a rectangle with user specified height and width. So for the default i have

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, height = 1, width = 1):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
```

but what does it mean by "create a rectangle with user specified height and width"

Comment: It sounds like they want you to use `input` in the constructor to ask the user for width and height, although that would generally be regarded as a bad idea. You'll need to ask your teacher for clarification though.

Comment: You need to go to your instructor for clarification, all you will get here is conjecture. To me, it sounds like your assignment is asking for a non-argument `__init__` and then an alternative constructor that takes height and width as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a rectangle with user specified height and width** means:

to ask the user (via a web page, or via a pop-up?) for the width and height values, and then your script will create a rectangle using those measurements.

For information about building a web page and reading a user's inputs, read about [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/)

Here's some information about asking a user for inputs:

[User input in dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438182/user-input-in-dialog-box)